# metarig works perfectly, but generated rig doesn't work at all

Tags: rigging

This is a separate mesh (shoe) on my character. It is parented to the metarig and then to the rig created by Rigify. The rig works all of my character, including the other shoe which is fine. I have reparented this mesh several times and weight painted. It now works fine with metarig, but not rig. Why is this?

[image: screenshot with face orientation overlay enabled]
<sup>(Edit: screenshot with face orientation overlay added)</sup>

Here is a link to the file: https://app.box.com/s/p8tcsuy5i39fk5gc4o848x3dfpapkgf5

Comment: Hi. I've added a screenshot to your question with the [Face Orientation overlay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598) enabled. As you can see, one shoe is red. This means that the normal ones are flipped and the mesh is inside out and causing the problems. Go to *Edit* mode, select the mesh, and flip the normals (Shift+N (=Recalculate outside) or Alt+N > Flip). After this, the weights must be recalculated or painted again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rigify (2.8) - automatic weight incorrect and issues with weight painting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174044/rigify-2-8-automatic-weight-incorrect-and-issues-with-weight-painting)

Comment: First thanks so much for responding. Must have something else going on because I did all that and it didn't help. Metarig works and rig does nothing to that shoe.

Comment: OK, now I got it to work. First I had to delete all vertex groups. Thanks soooooo Much!